# Can a Psicrystal be used with Ectopic Form?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, psionics

Psicrystals (Expanded Psionics Handbook) are manifestations of the Psion's consciousness on the physical plane, with the power to manifest ectoplasmic legs to move and climb. **Ectopic form** (Complete Psionics) allows you to create astral constructs with distinct appearances and specialties.

While it is clear if you did this you would only get to apply one shape to your psi crystal, I was wondering if the rules as written allow for the rules as interpreted to let something like this happen, as a variant of the **Elemental Envoy** and **Improved Psicrystal** (feat) themes.

I normally wouldn't ask a question like this, but it seems to me that Astral Constructs and Psi Crystals are both constructed in similar ways, with the exception that Astral Constructs are Temporary. So I figured if a psion can construct both, can they apply a "during construction modifier" to both, even though they are clearly trying to focus on Astral Constructs, I'm wondering if the Psicrystal can be ruled similar enough to receive a similar flavor text advantage?

additional information: The side effect of doing this to your Psicrystal is that it would resemble a crystalline familiar, like a snake, spider, or bird, instead of a faceted gemstone.

Comment: What system is this for?

Comment: Hi Tristian, welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. Please specify which game and edition you're playing -- we tend for literally thousands of different tabletop games here.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is for *D&D 3.5e* as the chances of another system having the feats Elemental Envoy and Ectopic Form are extremely low, but @doppelgreener is correct in that this question *still* needs a system tag. Guessing and getting it wrong is *worse* than the question staying on hold.

Comment: edited for clarity and edition tags. Sorry, still learning the site :)

Comment: OK, well I’ve voted for re-opening, so that should get it some attention and get it re-opened.

Comment: @Tristian Thanks for clarifying. :) I've reopened it.

Comment: I think, to a large degree, you've answered your own question with a *No.* What you can do if you like is rephrase the question to something like *Would a house rule saying that* A master with a psicrystal and the feat Ectopic Form can allow his psicrystal to assume that ectopic form *be unbalanced?* Then—as long as the house rule is sufficiently clear—the site can evaluate that house rule.

Answer (score 2):

### No, RAW does not have such an option...

...however, that is a very cool idea.

As such, here are some suggestions:

**1) Astral Construct, the Psicrystal, and your sculpting skill**

Somewhat controversial mostly due to a lack of specific rules which apply, but what is clear is that you can use the sculpting skill on your Astral Constructs for fine details. Such as a hollow cavity inside the Astral Construct. What is NOT clear in the RAW is the full import of being able to make such a cavity and place something, or someone, inside of it. Obviously, line of sight and line of effect are blocked by the construct, among other things.

Astral constructs are commanded with a mental action, if I recall correctly, and it might be a bit tough to get the psicrystal able to communicate with, and thus command, such a construct. If the psicrystal can speak out loud, and the construct accept spoken commands, then you have no problem.

**2) Your psicrystal already can look like a (very small) spider**

When the mobility (legs) option is activated, it looks a lot like a small spider.

**3) The (not permitted by RAW) idea of psicyrstal feats.**

If your DM is in the camp of allowing a psicrystal to take feats, even though advancement is listed as a non-ability, which would completely prevent such from happening RAW, then the psicrystal could take the Construct Body (err... that is *Skin of the Construct*) feat and wear the construct (since it shares your skills). While this is completely disallowed by RAW, it is a very cool, very fun idea.

Perhaps you could sell your DM on the idea of an "Emancipated Familiar" prestige class based on the Emancipated Spawn one, which would resolve the RAW issues.

Comment: Where can you find the "construct body" feat?

Comment: Complete Psionic... where it is apparently listed as "Skin of the Construct" unlike my memory recall.... I'll update the answer.